# Is it bad practise to use Type as a 'Property'?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am working with some old C# code at the moment, which basically uses derived types for the sole purpose of using the Type as a 'property', such as:

```
public abstract class Fruit
{
    public int Property { get; set; }
}

public class Apple : Fruit {}

public class Pear : Fruit {}
```

And then:

```
public void Foo(Fruit item)
{
    if(item is Apple)
    {
        // do something
        return;
    }
    if(item is Pear)
    {
        // do something
        return;
    }

    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("item");
}
```

I would have included an enum property on BaseClass to specify the 'type':

```
public class Fruit
{
    public int Property { get; set; }

    public FruitType Type { get; set; }
}

public enum FruitType
{
    Apple,
    Pear
}
```

and then used it thus:

```
public void Foo(Fruit item)
{
    switch(item.Type)
    {
        case FruitType.Apple:
            // do something
            break;
        case FruitType.Pear:
            // do something
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
}
```

I feel that the former pattern is a misuse of inheritence, but are there any advantages to it that I should consider before re-writing this code?

Comment: This is very much a design smell - both the original version, and the one with the enum. Use polymorphism instead. The one advantage I can think of is if you can't modify the class hierarchy you need to switch on.

Comment: In your second example why is the class still abstract? Shouldn't it rather be sealed?

Comment: @Eric yep shouldn't be abstract, updated

Comment: millimoose is right, both your versions of Foo are tightly coupled to the Fruit sub-classes. If you need to add another sub-class you are going to have to change Foo as well. This should be avoidable with a better design, e.g. using polymorphism so that Foo can just call a single method defined in Fruit, regardless of the actual sub-class being passed in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The standard "OO" way to deal with this situation is to make DoSomething an abstract method on Fruit. Then the caller just calls DoSomething, knowing that the implementation will do the right thing.

The downside of this approach is that it puts responsibility for working out all possible "somethings" that a user might possibly want onto the author of the abstract class.

That downside can be mitigated by using the "visitor pattern". The visitor pattern is a standard way to enable third parties to efficiently switch behaviours based on the runtime type of a value. You might consider researching it.

Your second approach -- discriminating the type with a tag -- is quite common and can be very efficient. Roslyn uses this technique extensively. It is considered by OO purists to be a bit smelly, but fortunately I am not an OO purist.

A variation on your second technique that I like is:

```
public enum FruitKind { Apple, Orange }
public abstract class Fruit
{
  private Fruit(FruitKind kind)
  {
      this.Kind = kind;
  }
  public FruitKind Kind { get; protected set; }
  private class Apple : Fruit
  {
      public Apple() : base(FruitKind.Apple) {}
  }
  public static Fruit MakeApple() { return new Apple(); }
  // similarly for orange
}
```

Now the *only* way that a Fruit user can determine the type is through the tag, because Apple and Orange are not accessible. You know that no third party is going to make their own Fruit because the only Fruit constructor is private.

Comment: Nice, I like the term 'Kind' much better than 'Type'. I'll look into the visitor pattern also.

Comment: @lockstock: It is a variation on the factory method pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) but I don't know of any formally recognized name for this pattern. I think of it as the "private subclass pattern" personally.